# Umbraco not showing up on domain - cPanel

Tags: umbraco

I am currently trying to install umbraco to my web server running cpanel

it is uploaded to www.benhussenet.co.uk/build. but when I go to the domain it says 404 nothing found.

Can anyone tell me and help me how to fix this please?

Many Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 1):

http://www.benhussenet.co.uk/build/default.aspx returns the code inside the ASP.NET page, which shows that you're on a server which doesn't have ASP.NET installed. This implies you're running on a *NIX webserver (which, Firebug'ing your site, it returns "Apache/2.2.14 (Unix)"). Umbraco is .NET and requires either a Windows web server, or a Linux server with Mono installed.

HTH,

Benjamin